# How to correct insert iframeResizer.contentWindow.js in jsf?

Tags: iframe-resizer

I try to fit iframe size with content and use lib https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

So, I created react component:

```
import React from "react";
import IframeResizer from "react-iframe-resizer-super";

const IFrameArea = () => {
  const url = "http://localhost:8080/app/jsf/data-payments.jsf";
  const iframeResizerOptions = {
    log: true,
    checkOrigin: false,
  };
  return (
    <IframeResizer src={url} iframeResizerOptions={iframeResizerOptions}/>
  );
};

export default IFrameArea;
```

and in header for all jsf-s inserted this

```
<h:outputScript library="iframeResizer" name="iframeResizer.contentWindow.js" />
```

So, I expected, that my component send message to content. Content will response using this iframeResizer.contentWindow.js and iframe will be resized. But there is

> [iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] No response from iFrame.
>   Check iFrameResizer.contentWindow.js has been loaded in iFrame

error message. So, can you help me, whats wrong?
p.s. I use [this](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) libriary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name="iframeResizer.contentWindow.js - is just path to js-lib

library - library name, you can use that already exists in your app.